# WordPress: Using existing Image-Hovereffect for other image objects

Tags: css, wordpress, hover

I´m trying to build up a new site. The work is nearly done, but I need a last detail. I´m using a grid with thumb/headline and link-function to detail sites.

I want to visualize the link-function with some hover-effects (delivered by my template).

This is the link to the project-site - and I´m looking for help on my mainpage:

https://emc.ow-media.de/

If you hover the thumb of the document or the thumbs of the three links at the end of the page, you can see a hover effect. I want to use this effect also on the grid element at the top (the 6 thumbs).

Can you give me a hint, how to get this working with CSS?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have sample already there. If you inspect the element, you can see how it works. The code the bottom elements use is as follows:

CSS:

```
figure.sc_image a {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}
figure.sc_image a {
    background-color: rgba(50,172,121,0.8) !important;
}
figure.sc_image a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<figure class="sc_image  sc_image_shape_square">
  <img src="https://emc.ow-media.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Leistungen-Potentialanalyse1.jpg" alt="">
  <a class="img_icon icon-file-pdf" href="http://emc.ow-media.de/was-wir-tun-detail"></a>
</figure>
```

Essentially what is happening, is that there is an invisible element `a`, with set opacity of 0. When someone hovers the element it gets to set the opacity of 1. The animation is done by the `transition` property, which eases the change of opacity. You can mimic the effect on your other elements.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to add the CSS for the 6 image elements without no hover effect. But I couldnt figure out how to address them?

I inspected the names like "element element_1613576190161  thumb " - but i couldnt find a way to address the objects with my CSS-Addition. Can you give me an hint here?

Thanks!

Comment: `.grid-items .layer-wrapper a` However, your HTML layout is not matching the expected HTML.

Comment: What do you mean with "matching the expected HTML"? 

Can you give me a hint about my next steps to get the hover-effect working?

Comment: Your HTML structure should match the one in the answer. Otherwise, you have to change CSS and it might not have the desired effect.